# Python Selenium - Clicking through pages without next button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to retrieve information from multiple webpages by clicking through them (see image 1 & 2). The problem is a) there is not next button and b) even though the page link contains a number for counting through, it does not react to changing the numbering manually (i.e. does not load the next page). This makes the task tricky.

Can anyone help on how to solve this?

here is what the structure of the link looks like (no functioning page) 
https://sample.io/address/ID#pageSize=100

[image: pagination structure]

[image: Source code]

UPDATE: Got it to work with help of Robbie W.. The code I am using is:

```
options.add_argument('windows-size = 1200 x 800')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)



browser.get('URL')
page_soup_1 = soup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
items_1 = page_soup_1.find_all("li", {"class": "page-item" })

LenofPage = pd.DataFrame()
count = pd.DataFrame()

for item in items_1 :
    string = str(item)
    Num = string[string.find('page-item')+23:string.find('\/li')-8]
    LenofPage = LenofPage.append({'LenofPage': Num}, ignore_index = True)

Max_pagenum = LenofPage.max()
Max_pagenum_1 = int(Max_pagenum)


count = 1
#items_1 = page_soup.find_all("li", {"class": "page-item active" 
}).next_sibling

while count <  Max_pagenum_1:
    link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(@class, "page-item") 
and contains(@class,"active")]/following-sibling::li/a')
    link.click()
    count = count + 1
    time.sleep(3)

print(count)
```

Comment: You can just click each button by number in a loop until the last page opened. Did you try it? Did you try anything?

Comment: Share your code. Share html with text format containing all elements. Please use (format)[htmlformatter.com] before share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may need slightly amending as you reach the final few pages, but I would suggest using XPath to find the `li` next to the currently selected `li`, and then click the `a` tag within it.

```
//li[contains(@class, "page-item") and contains(@class,"active")]/following-sibling::li/a
```

Comment: Perfect, works! Thank you! I extended the code to make it work with various pages, will post below